# Angular2 - How to clear the value of a texbox when it is hidden with *ngIf

Tags: angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have a control on the form. Attached to it is a directive *ngIf. I show/hide this control based on a certain expression.
When the condition evaluates to true, the control is shown. I type some text into the control.
Few moments later, the condition evaluates to false, hence the control is hidden from display.
Later on, the expression evaluates back to true, the control is shown with the value typed previously.

Is there a way to clear the control value once it is hidden? Maybe create a directive and attach it to a control?

In angular js I did that using a custom directive, but in Angular 2 still not sure how to go around that.

Thanks

```
(function () {
appModule.directive('destroyWhenHidden', ['$timeout', '$parse',
    function ($timeout, $parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',   // 'A' is the default, so you could remove this line
            link: function ($scope, element, $attrs) {

                var getField = function (fieldPath) {
                    // ex: fiedlPath: vm.poc.formalEducation
                    var fieldPieces, field;
                    if (fieldPath) {
                        fieldPieces = fieldPath.split(/[.]+/); // [vm,poc,formalEducation]
                        field = fieldPieces[fieldPieces.length - 1]; // formalEducation
                    }
                    else {
                        field = undefined;
                    }
                    return field;
                };

                // Get a callable function
                var callback = $parse($attrs.destroyF);

                $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                    // Call callback under parent $scope context, hence function()/vm.function() is found and executed
                    callback($scope, { field: getField($attrs.ngModel) });
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

})();

Comment: When the hide condition is true set [(ngModel)]="textFiled " variable of the text field to empty in your .ts file. it works in angular 4

Comment: Thank you. I have a form with around 30 controls, managing the state and condition is going to be hectic. I was hoping I can build a directive just like in angular js. I tried to build such thing, but the problem is that, once a control is hidden using ngIf, the rest of directives would't run as the parent control is out of DOM